# Quill editor: removes / resets the input value when it starts with number list

Tags: quill, react-quill, react-quilljs

I was trying out the Quill.js editor through their [playground](https://quilljs.com/playground/) but I noticed a weird issue when trying to type a number list, it automatically apply a tab and resets the number to `1.` when no previous text is added. And when you hit enter without adding any text after the number, the editor will automatically remove it.

To reproduce,

- Type `2.` then space, result will be the number is changed to `1.` and when you hit enter without adding any text, the number will be gone.

Comment: I had this issue too, since there wasn't any update after the installed version for Quill, I decided to replace it with another WYSIWYG editor